# Unable to access the Internet. Able to ping 1.1.1.1 but can't reach an internet server nor am I able to download updates from canonical

Tags: internet

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The last product I installed was Protonvpn.
Sequence of Events -
I logged off of Protonvpn
I logged off as a user
Powered down the PC

Next day:
-Powered on the computer
-Logged in as a user
-Started Firefox
-Attempted to access Yahoo.com
-Received message 'Unable to reach the server'
-There was a message to install Ubuntu updates
-Attempted to install but failed do to no internet connection

-Eventually contacted Proton, They recommended running 'protonvpn-cli d' in order to force a Proton disconnect. This did not work.

I know the WiFi card is working because I'm able to dual boot to the Windows O/S, which is what I'm on now.

Comment: Was the WiFi working **in Ubuntu** before Proton?

Comment: Yes. Ubuntu was working before and after installation of Proton. I had Proton installed and working for a little over a week prior to the current situation. I had powered off and back on several times as well without logging off of Proton. This all started when I logged of proton prior to shut down.

Comment: One other note, I tested to my wireless printer and was able to send a document to it.